# Java Serialization through Network, repasses same objects?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, deserialization

I'm going to layout the situation and the question is at the bottom.

I've got an object like so:

```
public class GameObject implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3081889342394131807L;
    public float x, y, vx, vy;
    public int size;
    public int mass;

    public GameObject()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        x = rand.nextInt(400);
        y = rand.nextInt(400);
        size = rand.nextInt(10);
        mass = size * size * size;
        vx = 0.3f;
        vy = 0.3f;
    }

    public void updateGameObject()
    {
        x+=vx;
        y+=vy;
    }
}
```

I've got a client-server setup using sockets: when the server starts up it creates a GameObject and adds it to a HashMap. Then the server loops, updating the object and sending the updated object. connection is a standard socket.

```
while (true)
{
    gameObject.updateGameObject();
    try {
        if (objOutputStream == null)
            objOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        objOutputStream.writeObject(o);
        objOutputStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

On the client side, I simply read the object and draw it to the screen. This is where the problem happens. I am definitely receiving an object with each loop, but it seems the fields of the GameObject are not changing when I read it.

```
while (true)
{
    try {
            if (objInputStream == null)
                objInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            return objInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

objInputStream and objOutputStream are both initialized above the while loops.

If I do a println() on the x and y values of the object I'm getting on the client, the values are never changing from their initial value.

When I do a println() on the x and y values on the server just before sending it, it prints out the correct values. Something like so:

```
Sending Object with 1, 1
Received Object with 1, 1
Sending Object with 2, 2
Received Object with 1, 1
Sending Object with 3, 3
Received Object with 1, 1
```

I feel like there is something basic I am missing. Though when I try finding other questions with this problem I can't seem to find one. Maybe one of you can provide me with some insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()` instead of `writeObject(),` or call `reset()` whenever you want to start again with a new set of values.

Comment: Thanks for adding this solution, it solves the problem more directly. It was mildly irritating to clone all the objects before sending them. If anyone is curious about why you should use these methods instead of the normal writeObject(), read pobrelkey's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectOutputStream` tries to make serializing complex graphs of objects painless by not re-writing to the stream any object you've written to it previously (as determined by referential equality, not `equals()`).

A lazy solution would be to implement `Cloneable` and `clone()` your object before sending - but unless you're on a thoroughly ancient JDK, you'll want to call [`writeUnshared()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared%28java.lang.Object%29) instead, as it will write a "fresh" copy of your object rather than a reference to a previous version.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a fresh `ObjectOutputStream` each time you write an object, to avoid this problem. Then you wouldn't need to `clone` it. I'm not sure which approach would be more efficient.

Comment: @RobinGreen No, that just causes more problems. How does the receiver know when to create a new `ObjectInputStream?`

Comment: Not a good answer. reset() does it in one line of code, instead of having to implement Cloneable in all objects concerned.

Comment: This solution did work for me, but I'll likely change it to either reset or writeUnshared; I don't see the point in creating a bunch of extra objects if I don't have to. Thanks for telling me about clone (didn't know of it before) and for explaining why the objects seemed to send outdated data. Will try to remember to upvote when I get enough reputation.

Comment: No worries - I wrote my answer off the top of my head, not being aware of `writeUnshared()`.  Have now edited to avoid misleading the unwary (and upvoted the other answer days ago).